# Can I close an ethereum smart contract?

Tags: altcoin

If I create a smart contract and coin, can I for example some day close the contract and these coins are useless or can not be used for example?
Is it possible or not?

Comment: Yes, you can implement a pausable token, or just suicide the contract

Comment: and if for example one exchanger is still my token listed and i suicide the token; close it and pause it, or like you say destruct completely the token what will happen with the tokens listed on the exchanger, he can still trade these tokens?

Comment: They can trade within the exchange, but no withdrawals or deposits will be possible. Any sane exchange would delist you if that happens.

Answer (score 2):

If the contract supports such functionality, then yes.

You basically have two options:

1) Write code to deny usage of the contract based on some criteria. For example you can write a function which, when called, disables all other functionality in the contract.

2) Implement a self destruct function in the contract. This will remove the contract and it can no longer be used after that. This is the hammer approach and not very...subtle. Details here: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#self-destruct

Comment: and if for example one exchanger is still my token listed and i suicide the token; close it and pause it, or like you say destruct completely the token what will happen with the tokens listed on the exchanger, he can still trade these tokens?

Comment: Please don't double-post your questions. This was answered above.

Answer (score 2):

The Open-Zeppelin library for Solidity has a few life-cycle contracts which handle scenarios like the one you describe. You can find them all here:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/lifecycle

> Destructible.sol

This is the one that most closely resembles what you are looking to do, and supports two functions:

```
function destroy() public onlyOwner {
  selfdestruct(owner);
}

function destroyAndSend(address _recipient) public onlyOwner {
  selfdestruct(_recipient);
}
```

First it takes advantage of another Open-Zeppelin library called `Ownable.sol` which allows a contract to have a specified address as the owner of the contract. By default, it is the contract creator.

Then `Destructible.sol` enables the owner to specifically destroy the contract, either sending any remaining ETH balance to themselves or a specific recipient.

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

// Set the contract name "Bank_A"
// Set numbers of clients who opening account in Bank_A 
// Get the balances and address of clients 
// Define the address of the BankA owner
contract Bank_A {
    uint8 private clientCount;
    mapping (address => uint) private balances;
    address owner;
    


  // Log the event about a deposit being made by an address and its amount
    event LogDepositMade(address indexed accountAddress, uint amount);

    // Constructor is "payable" so it can receive the initial funding of 10, 
    // required to reward the first client 1 ether
    constructor() public payable {
        require(msg.value == 10 ether, "10 ether initial funding required");
        /* Set the owner to the creator of this contract */
        owner = msg.sender;
        clientCount = 0;
    }

    /// @notice a customer open an account in bank_A, 
    /// giving the first customer 1 ether as reward
    /// @return The balance of the customer after enrolling
    function enroll() public returns (uint) {
        if (clientCount < 1) {
            balances[msg.sender] = 1 ether;
            clientCount += 1;
        }
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }

    /// @notice Deposit ether into bank, requires method is "payable"
    /// @return The balance of the user after the deposit is made
    function deposit() public payable returns (uint) {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        emit LogDepositMade(msg.sender, msg.value);
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }

    /// @notice Withdraw ether from bank
    /// @return The balance remaining for the user
    function withdraw(uint withdrawAmount) public returns (uint remainingBal) {
        // Check enough balance available, otherwise just return balance
        if (withdrawAmount <= balances[msg.sender]) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= withdrawAmount;
            msg.sender.transfer(withdrawAmount);
        }
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }

    /// @notice Just reads balance of the account requesting, so "constant"
    /// @return The balance of the user
    function balance() public view returns (uint) {
        return balances[msg.sender];
    }

    /// @return The balance of the Bank_A contract
    function depositsBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    
    ///@only the bank owner can close the bank
    function closebank() public view return(unit) {
      
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more details? like an explanation what are you trying to do to answer the question.